# Magento 2 REST API Customer Custom Attribute

Tags: rest, api, magento, magento2

The Magento 2 REST API Documentation explains a way to set custom_attributes on a customer when updating or creating it. http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_20.html#/

Unfortunately I couldn't get this to work...

My POST and PUT JSON request data is :

```
{
    "customer": {
        "custom_attributes": [
            {
                "attribute_code": "firstname",
                "value": "TEST"
            }
        ],
        "email": "someone@exaxmple.com",
        "extension_attributes": [],
        "firstname": "Someone",
        "gender": null,
        "lastname": "Else",
        "middlename": null,
        "taxvat": null,
        "website_id": "1"
    }
}
```

The Customer is created but the Firstname is not "TEST".
Is there anyone who had the same problem and fixed it? Please let me know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess is that, since `Firstname` is an existing Out-Of-The-Box attribute - the OOTB attribute name-value mapping assignment will take precedence.

Could you try again, with a unique custom attribute name (i.e. something that doesn't clash with OOTB attribute names)

You will need to DEFINE a custom-customer-attribute before you can use the M2 API to perform operations on that custom-customer-attribute.

This StackExchange thread - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88245/magento2-create-a-customer-custom-attribute - has additional information on how to go about setting up a custom-customer-attribute.

Comment: I did the exact same thing with a item and attribute "description" which did work. Why isn't this working for Customers? I couldn't find the place in Magento 2 code where this request is handled, maybe you can provide me with the location?

Comment: - Looking at the WebAPI defined (`Magento\Customer\etc\webapi.xml`) for the method in question the `POST /V1/customers` API call is handled by `Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface::createAccount()`

- According to the di.xml (`Magento\Customer\etc\di.xml`) `Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface` is implemented by `Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement` (`Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement.php`)

- I'd recommend using Xdebug to step through the code to figure out how/why the attribute doesn't update.

Comment: Thank you for figuring it out @Sharath Kumar. My conclusion: It's just not possible and Magento 2 doesn't do anything with the custom_attributes on the Customer API. Unlike the Product API. I wonder why the documentation says you can...