# Magento 2.1 - Cant update Customer Custom Attribute via REST

Tags: rest, magento, custom-attribute

I am trying to update a Custom Attribute in a Customer

However the PUT request is not working...

```
{
"customer":{
    "id":111,
    "group_id": 1,
    "email":"abcd@com",
    "firstname": "first",
    "lastname": "last",
    "taxvat": "123456789",
    "website_id": 1
},
"custom_attributes": 
[
    {
        "attribute_code": "customer_erp_id",
        "value": "66666"
    }       
]
```

}

Endpoint ..../rest/V1/customers/111

There's an existing post [Magento 2 REST API Customer Custom Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46254405/magento-2-rest-api-customer-custom-attribute)
which seems to conclude that this is not possible

As it is a bit old I was wandering if anybody was able to get this working...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, but I solved it easily just changing the custom_attributes node inside the main body.

```
{
"customer": {
    "email":"roberto@test.com.mx",
    "firstname":"Roberto Carlos",
    "lastname":"Castillo",
    "storeId": 1,
    "websiteId":1,
    "gender":"1",
    "custom_attributes" : [
            {"attribute_code" : "foo", "value" : "bar" }
    ]
},
"password":"Test12345"
```

}